# MVC controller post entire model to remote api action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, post

I have an API I would like to call from my front end MVC site. These two applications run on separate servers on the same network.

The API Controller has functions similar to:

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
public class VerifyMyModelController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public MyResponse Post(MyModel model)
    {
        return MyHelper.VerifyMyModel(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<MyResponse> PostAsync(MyModel model)
    {
        return await MyHelper.VerifyMyModel(model);
    }
// ... Gets below as well
}
```

Where `MyHelper` performs model verfication, DB lookups etc... and returns a common response object with response code, database id etc

My front end MVC site has a form the user fills out, this data gets posted to the local controller which I would like to forward on to the API. The API application is not accessible to the public, so I cannot post directly to it using AJAX etc. It must come from the sites controller.

I have tried the following but get a `500 internal server error` as a response

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<MyResponse> VerifyAsync(MyModel model)
{
    var MyServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServer"];
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

    var requestUri = string.Format(@"http://{0}/api/VerifyMyModel/", MyServer);

    using (var c = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await c.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, json);
    }
    ...
}
```

The `var response` contains the error message response 500.

I have also tried using a query string:

```
public string GetQueryString(object obj)
{
    var properties = from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                        where p.GetValue(obj, null) != null
                        select p.Name + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p.GetValue(obj, null).ToString());

    return String.Join("&", properties.ToArray());
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<MyResponse> VerifyAsync(MyModel model)
{
    var MyServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServer"];
    string queryString = GetQueryString(model);
    var requestUri = string.Format(@"http://{0}/api/VerifyMyModel/?{1}", MyServer, queryString);

    using (var c = new HttpClient()){
        var response = await c.GetAsync(requestUri); // API Also has GET methods
    }
}
```

But the `querystring` method returns a `405 method not allowed` response.

The `MyModel` is part of a shared class library with common models in it and is included in both applications.

Is there a better way of posting the entire model to the remote api action?

Thanks.

*Edit

RouteConfig of API:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I added the following to the `HomeController` of the API's MVC site, to test it and I receive back the expected result, without error:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestVerifyMyModel(MyModel model)
{
        var api = new VerifyMyModelController();
        var res = await api.PostAsync(model);

        return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

So I know that the `PostAsync` Action of the controller works.. I just cant get it to work when called remotely.

I also enabled `Failed Request Tracing` on the server and have [uploaded the generated XML file](https://mega.nz/#!nkZFBAyA!Ruqcj-iM29YZtwTc-lFYS3QNsKjBPIvwik8ku-br20A). It doesn't mean anything to me but thought it might help.

Comment: Show the route config of the remote web api

Comment: You mentioned it's a remote web API, is it hosted on the same domain? If not, you have to enable cross-site requests, if you didn't already

Comment: I have added the RouteConfig of the API. API Server is on the same domain, accessed using `http://ServerName/IISSiteName` I have added an `AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute` that I found through google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted route config looks more like your MVC route config than a Web Api one. But if it is the Web Api config, then shouldn't you be adding the **ActionName** to your url.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<MyResponse> VerifyAsync(MyModel model)
    {
        var MyServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServer"];
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

        var requestUri = string.Format(@"http://{0}/api/VerifyMyModel/PostAsync", MyServer);

        using (var c = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await c.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, json);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Update: Sample code to retrieve Model from HttpClient response

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServer"]);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/VerifyMyModel/PostAsync");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var myResponseModel = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyResponseModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The route config is the default one VS created, I am sure I selected an MVC API solution.. I updated my code to match your answer but my `response` is `500 internal server error: An error has occurred.` nothing gets logged to our elmah log, so I can't work out what is causing it.

Comment: I added an additional test I performed to the original question, the API works when it calls itself, just not from anywhere else it seems.

Comment: There might be some confusion. When you create an ASP.net MVC template + Web API you should get 2 config files: RouteConfig.cs (MVC)WebApiConfig.cs (Web API). And you should have 2 types of controllers MVC and API. So you might need to recheck which one calls which.

Comment: Ah, I do have those two files. Is the difference in controller just what it inherits? `:Controller` vs `:ApiController`? Thanks for your help. One last quick thing, `response` has the status code in it `200` now. How do I make it have the `MyResponse` object instead? That is what should be returned by the API call.. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer with a sample code to retrieve the Model object (assuming you as adding it to your response in the api call). Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I am now having troubles with the server not seeing the post data. If you get a chance, [could you take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755878/mvc-api-cannot-retrieve-postasync-json-data)?